# how to avoid error of adding string to generator expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I need to iterate over folder names and then over images but I've got this error.  May someone tell me how to avoid the error?

```
path = '/.../'

dirs = next(os.walk(path))[1] # get my folder names inside my directory

for i in dirs:
    for img in os.listdir(path+(x for x in dirs)): <------ TypeError: must be str, not generator
        img_path = os.path.join(path,img)  
        print(img_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the previous line where you're trying to add `path` to a generator exp:

```
path+(x for x in dirs)
```

You should join the `path` to the directory name using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
for dir in dirs:   
   for img in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, dir)):
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
path = '/home/'


dirs = next(os.walk(path))[1]  # get folder names inside directory

for i in dirs:
    for img in os.listdir(path+i):
        img_path = os.path.join(path,img)  
        print(img_path)
```

In the line below, you're trying to concatenate the generator object and the string `path`. Instead, you can use `i` itself, as above.

```
path+(x for x in dirs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're needlessly complicating your code by using `listdir`. This:

```
import os, os.path
path = '/.../'
for d, _, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        img_path = os.path.join(d, f)
        print(img_path)
```

should be enough.